# Botão que ao clicar envia para localização?

Tags: android

Como configurar um botão para que quando clicado abra o maps e envie o usuario para um endereço?

Comment: Como assim: teletransporte?

Comment: Gps, ao clicar no botão envia pro maps

Comment: Deve te ajudar: http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/02/advance-android-google-map-2-tutorial-with-example.html#.WTgxjuvyuUk 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446811/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-on-map-in-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302112/how-to-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-location-where-user-taps-on-the-map-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
private void abrirRota(){

    /**
     * Nossa intenção será um google.navigation
     * Temos os seguintes parametros:
     * q= [Destino, endereço ou Latitude e longitude]; OBRIGATÓRIO!
     * mode= [define o método de transporte] {d= condução, w = caminhada, b = bicicleta}; OPCIONAL
     * avoid=[define os recursos que a rota deve tentar evitar] {t = pedágios, h = estradas, f=  balsas} OPCIONAL
     */

    final String url = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),  "google.navigation:q=Heitor+Stockler+de+França,+470+-+Centro+Cívico,+Curitiba+-+PR");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, cria a atividade do mapa, aqui tem um [Exemplo](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).

Depois, cria um método pra abrir a atividade e associa ao `onClick` do botão, algo como

```
public void getLocalizacao(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), Mapa.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Voltando à atividade do mapa, pode setar a localização:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng congresso = new LatLng(-15.7997586, -47.8647535);
```

E pra ficar legal, adiciona uma animação pra onde você setou a localização

`CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(congresso)
                .zoom(16).bearing(0)
                .build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));`